# Creating a new column which contain similar words

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have a column which includes similar words in a pandas dataframe:

```
My_Column
thereisacat
there-is_cat
mummy
mommy
mammy
Daniel-1
Daniel 
Bob
```

I would like to create a column where I include per each row the most similar words, for example:

```
My_Column        Similar_to
thereisacat     [there-is_cat]
there-is_cat    [thereisacat]
mummy           [mommy, mammy]
mommy           [mummy, mammy]
mammy           [mummy, mommy]
Daniel-1        [Daniel]
Daniel          [Daniel-1]
Bob             []
```

To calculate the similarity I am considering the following:

(1)

```
import nltk
nltk.edit_distance()
```

(2)

```
 import difflib
        seq = difflib.SequenceMatcher()
```

(3)

```
 import jellyfish
    jellyfish.levenshtein_distance() # or jellyfish.jaro_distance()
```

I would like to know how I could apply one of these three algorithm for creating a column which lists the most similar words to those in `My_Column`.

If I am right (maybe not my code) what I should do is to create a matrix which includes all the rows within My_Column as columns as well in order to assign a value of similarity then extracting the most similar.
Something like this:

```
def sim_metric(col1, col2): # actually should be more
    return SequenceMatcher(None, df[col1], df[col2]).ratio()

df['Similar_to'] = df.apply(sim_metric,
                          axis=1)
```

Comment: Please show us the code that you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a similarity matrix and then filter the matrix using some thresh and append the results.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk

similarity = {}
similiar_words = []
thresh = 3

df = pd.read_clipboard()

for word in df.My_Column:
    scores = {}
    for match in df.My_Column:
        score = nltk.edit_distance(word, match)
        scores[match] = score
    similarity[word] = scores

matrix_df = pd.DataFrame(similarity) 

for value in matrix_df.to_dict('dict').values():
    similiar_words.append([key for key, val in value.items() if 0 < val < thresh])

df['Similar_to'] = similiar_words

df

Out[1]: 
      My_Column      Similar_to
0   thereisacat  [there-is_cat]
1  there-is_cat   [thereisacat]
2         mummy  [mommy, mammy]
3         mommy  [mummy, mammy]
4         mammy  [mummy, mommy]
5      Daniel-1        [Daniel]
6        Daniel      [Daniel-1]
7           Bob              []
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
from itertools import product

unique_words = set(df['My_column'])

similarity_matrix = {key: distance_algo(key[0], key[1]) for key in list(product(list(unique_words),repeat = 2))}

similar_to_map = {}
for word in unique_words:
  wlist = [(sword, similarity_matrix[(word, sword)]) for sword in unique_words if sword is not word]
  wlist = wlist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
  similar_to_map[word] = wlist[0][0]

df['Similar_to'] = df['My_column'].apply(lambda x: similar_to_map[x], axis=0)
```

Comment: thanks Serial Lazer. What is distance_algo? It is not defined

Comment: Thats your edit_distance or any other algo that you described in your question